# Button to like one post actually likes all posts

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css, variables

I created a like and dislike button but when I click like it likes all of my posts, here is my code:

```
$sql_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE mem_id='$id' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 30");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_posts)){

$postid = $row["id"];
$poster_id = $row["mem_id"];
$post_body = $row["post_body"];
$notokinarray = array("fucker", "ass", "shit", "fuck", "fucking", "damn", "asshole", "cunt", "damnit");
$okinarray   = array("******", "***", "****", "****", "*******", "****", "*******", "****", "******");
$post_body = str_replace($notokinarray, $okinarray, $post_body);
$post_body = ($activeLinkObject -> makeActiveLink($post_body));
$post_date = $row["post_date"];
$convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($post_date));
$whenPost = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));
$device = $row["device"];
$postlikes = $row["likes"];
$postlikers = $row["likers"];
$postdislikes = $row["dislikes"];
$postdislikers = $row["dislikers"];
```

like function (this is where the problem seems to be)

```
$visitor = $_SESSION['id'];
        if (isset($_POST['likeIt'])) {
            if ($postlikers != "") { 

                $postlikers = "$postlikers,$visitor"; } else { $postlikers = "$visitor"; 
                $UpdateArrayLikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET likers='$postlikers' WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                $UpdateArrayLikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET likes=likes + 1 WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                header("location: profile.php?id=$id");
                }
        }

    // Inner sql query
$sql_mem_data = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname FROM myMembers WHERE id='$poster_id' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_mem_data)){
        $uid = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["username"];
        $fname = $row["firstname"];
        $lname = $row["lastname"];
        $commentForm = '
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="profile.php?id='.$id.'" style="padding-top:-10;">
                <textarea onfocus="value=\'\'" value="Write a comment..." name="comments" id="comments" rows="1"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="comment" id="comment" value="comment" />
            </form>';



        if (isset($_POST['dislikeIt'])) {
            $thisPostDislikers = explode(",", $postdislikers);
            if (!in_array($visitor, $thisPostDislikers)) {
                if ($postdislikers != "") { $postdislikers = "$postdislikers,$visitor"; } else { $postdislikers = "$visitor"; }
                $UpdateArrayDislikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET dislikers='$postdislikers' WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                $UpdateArrayDislikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET dislikes=dislikes + 1 WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                header("location: profile.php?id=$id");
            }
        }
        if ($id) {
            $thisPostLikers = explode(",", $postlikers);
            if (in_array($visitor, $thisPostLikers)){
                $likesPost = true;
            }
        }
        if ($id) {
            $thisPostDislikers = explode(",", $postdislikers);
            if (in_array($visitor, $thisPostDislikers)){
                $dislikesPost = true;
            }
        }

        if ($fname != "") {$name = "$fname $lname"; } // (I added usernames late in  my system, this line is not needed for you)
        ///////  Mechanism to Display Pic. See if they have uploaded a pic or not  //////////////////////////
        $ucheck_pic = "members/$uid/image01.jpg";
        $udefault_pic = "members/0/image01.png";
        if (file_exists($ucheck_pic)) {
            $post_pic = '<div style="overflow:hidden; height:40px;"><img src="' . $ucheck_pic . '" width="40px" border="0" /></div>'; 
        } else {
            $post_pic = '<div style="overflow:hidden; height:40px;"><img src="' . $udefault_pic . '" width="40px" border="0" /></div>'; 
        }
        if ((!$likesPost) && (!$dislikesPost)) {
        $postDisplayList .= '
            <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; border-top:none;" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '">' . $post_pic . '</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="90%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
                        <span class="liteGreyColor textsize11"> ' . $whenPost . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '"><strong>' . $name . '</strong></a>
                        via <em>' . $device . '</em></span><br />
                        <span> ' . $post_body . '</span>
                        <span>
                            <form id="likeForm" name="likeForm" method="post" action="" style="padding-bottom:-20;">
                                <input type="submit" name="likeIt" value="Like" />
                                <input type="submit" name="dislikeIt" value="Dislike" />&nbsp;'.$postlikes.'&nbsp;people like this.
                            </form>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $commentList . ' </td>
                    <td>' . $commentForm . ' </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
    } else if ((!$likesPost) && ($dislikesPost)) {
        $postDisplayList .= '
            <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; border-top:none;" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '">' . $post_pic . '</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="90%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
                        <span class="liteGreyColor textsize11"> ' . $whenPost . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '"><strong>' . $name . '</strong></a>
                        via <em>' . $device . '</em></span><br />
                        <span> ' . $post_body . '</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>' . $commentList . ' </td>
                    <td>' . $commentForm . ' </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
    } else if ((!$dislikesPost) && ($likesPost)) {
        $postDisplayList .= '
            <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; border-top:none;" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '">' . $post_pic . '</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="90%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
                        <span class="liteGreyColor textsize11"> ' . $whenPost . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '"><strong>' . $name . '</strong></a>
                        via <em>' . $device . '</em></span><br />
                        <span> ' . $post_body . '</span>
                        <span>                          
                            <form id="dislikeForm" name="dislikeForm" method="post" action="">
                                <input type="submit" name="dislikeIt" value="Dislike" />&nbsp;'.$postlikes.'&nbsp;people like this.
                            </form>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td>' . $commentList . ' </td></tr>
                <tr><td>' . $commentForm . ' </td></tr>
            </table>';
    } else {
        $postDisplayList .= '
            <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; border-top:none;" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '">' . $post_pic . '</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="90%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
                        <span class="liteGreyColor textsize11"> ' . $whenPost . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $poster_id . '"><strong>' . $name . '</strong></a>
                        via <em>' . $device . '</em></span><br />
                        <span> ' . $post_body . '</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;'.$postlikes.'&nbsp;people like this.' . $commentList . ' </td></tr>
            </table>';
    }
}

}
```

the like function in the first while loop makes the user like all the posts.

Comment: where's `$postid` getting set in the second snippet?

Comment: $postid is declared farther up, that code I actually forget, thanks for commenting

Answer (score 0):

You get all your posts by your poster id.
Then loop through those posts.
Then inside the loop, after first while loop, you again get your user data by myMembers table using poster id.
And inside the second while loop you update the data for current post id.

Since first while loop iterates through all your posts, you update details for every post id in your second inner while loop.

So problem is with SQL query for first outer while loop I think. Or may be what you missed is that you need to include

```
                $UpdateArrayLikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET likers='$postlikers' WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                $UpdateArrayLikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET likes=likes + 1 WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                header("location: profile.php?id=$id");
```

inside

```
if ($postlikers != "") { $postlikers = "$postlikers,$visitor"; } else { $postlikers = "$visitor"; }
```

condition.

Edit: You should update  post table for likers and likes if only $postlikers is not empty. Something like this.

```
if ($postlikers != "") { 

 $postlikers = "$postlikers,$visitor"; } else { $postlikers = "$visitor"; 
 $UpdateArrayLikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET likers='$postlikers' WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
 $UpdateArrayLikers = mysql_query("UPDATE post SET likes=likes + 1 WHERE id='$postid'") or die (mysql_error());
                    header("location: profile.php?id=$id");

}
```

Comment: so should I move the if function for adding likes to the first while loop

Comment: see the edit. I think you can move this "if" condition block out side of the second inner "while" loop (which is actually act like "if" condition), if it is not necessary to check whether "myMembers" tables contain a row with id $poster_id before updating "post" table.

Comment: I will update the post with new code and see if it works or not

Comment: It didn't work, does the code look like what you told me to change it to?